# XSS through modifying a UI element value?

Tags: xss, injection, ajax

I send an AJAX request and when the HTML loads back, I retrieve the values of some UI elements at the client side and present them to the user, like so:

```
var displ="<h1>"+$( "#myslider" ).slider( "values", 0)+</h1>
$("mydiv").append(displ);
```

Can the value of `#myslider` or any other element like a select box be changed to a value like `<script>...</script>` and create a XSS injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

Longer answer: **Yes, if** the `<select>` already contains an `<option>` with an XSS payload in (somehow - see below), and also it kind of depends on what the slider() function does. If you take your other example (a select input) then using val() without sanitising the content will cause this issue. Unless slider() sanitises HTML content in some way, it may do the same.

This is a form of DOM-based cross-site scripting.

Working example (with a `<select>`): https://jsfiddle.net/54bv5t3j/

Tested in Chrome for Mac OS X.

```
addString();
$("select").change(addString);

function addString() {
    var displ=$("select").val()+"<br/>";
    $("div").append(displ);
}
```

Where there is one `<select>` and one `<div>` on the page.

---

**Practical Exploitation**

The other question is when can this practically be exploited by an attacker? To make this practical for an attacker, the value of a select `<option>` would have to come from an untrusted source, either directly from a user controllable request parameter (including HTTP headers, cookies etc) for reflected XSS, or where the payload is loaded from storage (database etc) for stored XSS.

The example above already has the XSS payload in the page, so it is basically assuming that the untrusted input has already occurred.

**Example #1**

Here's an example that is entirely DOM-based. JavaScript sets the value of an option to the URL location hash. So if the victim is lured onto a page with an XSS payload after a # in the URL, the XSS can be triggered.

https://jsfiddle.net/tkgos3n0/1/

**Example #2**

I use a server-side technology (PHP in this case) to create a page with a dynamically generated `<option>` element from a user-controllable URL parameter. Because I'm a super-clever developer, I know that if the double-quotes can be escaped, the page will be vulnerable to reflected XSS on the `<option>` element itself, so I make sure I remove double-quotes from the string, thinking that I will be safe.

```
// User controlled parameter
$value = $_GET("value"); 
// "Sanitise" the value by removing double-quotes
$sanitised = str_replace('"', '', $value);
// Output to the page
echo "<option value=\"" . $sanitised . "\">Choose Me!</option>";
```

Because the developer has sanitised double-quotes, this issue cannot be *directly* exploited. I.e. the attacker can put all kinds of characters inside the option value, but he can't inject things like `">` to end the option element and start a new one.

However, due to the DOM-based XSS, the Javascript will still take this string, potentially containing HTML elements, and output it directly onto the page. Of course, the developer should have:

1. Performed HTML entity encoding on PHP ([ref](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes))
2. Performed HTML and Javascript escaping in the Javascript code ([ref](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_then_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Subcontext_within_the_Execution_Context))

References are OWASP cheatsheets.